# Table borders not straight

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I am creating a html maze using tables and for some reason, the borders dont show up correctly. Instead of nice straight lines, the borders show up as diagonal blobs instead. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my example : http://thomaswd.com/maze.

Output:

[image]

My CSS:

```
section .l {
    border-left:20px solid #ff9c00;
}

section .r {
    border-right:20px solid #ff9c00;
}

section .t {
    border-top:20px solid #ff9c00;
}

section .b {
    border-bottom:20px solid #ff9c00;
}

section table {
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    border:20px solid #FF9C00;
}
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261703/set-css-border-to-end-in-a-90-instead-of-a-45-degree-angle

Comment: Not really a duplicate of that... Also you may want to consider using `border-collapse: collapse` on the `table` element. Should get rid of those gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `border: 20px solid transparent;` from your `section table tr td` selector (not shown in your code sample) and it looks fine.

[image]

Comment: Transparent borders are a good way to make triangles using only CSS. Worth remembering if you need a speech box style comment display or something.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 CSS `transform` works too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8867645/918414