# Make borders not overlap visually

Tags: css

I am trying to make some kind of vertical menu with hovering state. Im my mind I want each menu item to have color 1-px strip on hover and 1px bottom border. I cannot use them both because borders overlap with 45 degrees, therefore I will have bottom border not cobering entire menu item width. Here I have something almost working http://jsfiddle.net/Wa568/1/ by applying:

```
div.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; top: 0px; left: 0; right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

trick. Borders do not overlap by 45 degrees now, but what I want is to have black bottom 1px border all the time (when not hovered) covering entire menu item block, and when hover green left border should appear overlapping **completely** left bottom part of bottom border.

Solutions with wrap inside block with width 100% and top:-1, and jquery manipulation are not accepted.

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14845818/2101267

Comment: might also work, as I can see but for a bit different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job for you. Pure CSS. No need for additional elements.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Wa568/3/

CSS:

```
div.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
div.box:hover {
    border-left: 10px solid #0a0;
}
div.box:after {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:-10px;
    width:calc(100% + 10px);
    height:1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;    
    content: " ";
}
div.box:hover:after {
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">awesome content</div>
```