# How to create a border that fully covers the adjacent corners in CSS?

Tags: css, border

I have a div with a 1px border and I'm trying to create a 3px border in another color to that div. I'm using this code:

```
box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 3px solid #3F9BD0;
}
```

but at the corners the border is not good, see image:
[image: bad border]

How can I make this border look good, like this:
[image: desired border with right-angled corners]

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15tory3z/

Comment: Can you add HTML and CSS and create jsfiddle.net demo

Comment: Yes fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15tory3z/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261703/set-css-border-to-end-in-a-90-instead-of-a-45-degree-angle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could draw these with inset shadows and padding :

```css
div {
  padding:12px 5px 5px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 10px #3F9BD0, inset 4px 0 gray, inset -4px 0 gray, inset 0 -4px  gray
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

or just an outset top shadow

```css
div {
 
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  border:2px solid gray;
  border-top:none;
  box-shadow:  0 -10px #3F9BD0;
  margin-top:12px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

else, `background` gradient could be used and even animated 2 examples : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC or http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pKwby

Comment: *This* is truly the answer. No need for `:after`.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of `border-top`, try using the [`:after`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) pseudo-element to recreate the effect you want.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.box:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  top: -5px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  padding: 1px;
  left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Choice 2:

Use [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, dodgerblue 5%, #fff 5%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, dodgerblue 5%, #fff 5%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, dodgerblue 5%, #fff 5%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, dodgerblue 5%, #fff 5%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, dodgerblue 5%, #fff 5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: How about that -1px at corner top left and top right?

Comment: look at it now @AlbaStar i added `padding:1px` and `left:-1px`

Comment: You can try choice 2 if you don't like the first one @AlbaStar

Answer (score 7):

This also puts a line on top:

```css
.box1 {
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -30px 0 #3F9BD0;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use css `:after` pseudo-class, [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

```css
.box_big {
  border: 10px solid #ddd;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box_big:after{
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top:-10px; left:-10px; right:-10px;
    content: " ";
    z-index: 2;
    background: red;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box:after{
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top:-3px; left:-1px; right:-1px;
    content: " ";
    z-index: 2;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_big">
    big box
</div>
<hr />
<div class="box">
    your box
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the css borders. The only way to properly do that is using `:after` or `:before` pseudoelements.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15tory3z/6/)

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
.box:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content:'';
    /* Positioning */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* Color */
    background-color: #3F9BD0;
}
```

Comment: You can also use box-shadow. I think it's much cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.box {
  outline: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border-top: 10px solid #3F9BD0;
  min-width:100px;
  min-height:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/4258/outlines#t=201608141421248252498

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old but I thought I'd make a suggestion that worked for me in a similar situation.

I just set `border-width: 0;` and that took away the mitered ends and made them nice and square for a button that I had a bottom-border applied.